# how to change system time in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

I need to change system time and date on my xubuntu to do some QA testing does anyone know how to do it? 
I tried going into system manager -> time and date setting 
every time i change the time it keeps going back to current time.

Comment: none of the suggestion works for me

Comment: 1/ Disable automatic date& time 2/ Run the date command in a terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me on Ubuntu 18.04

- Disable the NTP server

  ```
  sudo timedatectl set-ntp false
  sudo timedatectl set-time "2019-12-30 $(date +%R:%S)"
  ```
- The result.

  ```
  emmet@ansmachine:~$ date
  Mon Des 30 05:08:21 CET 2019
  emmet@ansmachine:~$ date
  Mon Des 30 05:08:22 CET 2019
  emmet@ansmachine:~$ date
  Mon Des 30 05:08:23 CET 2019
  ```

  If you want to go back to original dates (pre-changes), just enable the NTP once again.

  ```
  sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
  ```

Answer (score 1):

solve it. I had to install the ntp setting first to prevent the system to automatically change time and date.

sudo apt-get install ntp

unlock the date system -> change to manual -> then it works